# Data not being displayed in a listview from SQLite in android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listview

I have successfully created a database and inserted data into it.However when retrieving the data and displaying it in a listview ,the data is not being displayed.I am unsure as to where my problem lies.I have researched in S/O and other tutorials but cannot seem to find what suits my code.The following is what i have tried:

**DBHelper.java** which extends **SQLiteOpenHelper**

```js
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MyDBName.db";
public static final String CONTACTS_TABLE_NAME = "contacts";
public static final String CONTACTS_COLUMN_ID = "id";
public static final String CONTACTS_COLUMN_TITLE = "title";
public static final String CONTACTS_COLUMN_AMOUNT = "amount";
public static final String CONTACTS_COLUMN_DESC = "description";

private HashMap hp;

public DBHelper(Context context)
{
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME , null, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.execSQL(
            "create table contacts " +
                    "(id integer primary key, title text,amount text,description text)"
    );
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS contacts");
    onCreate(db);
}

public boolean insertContact  (String title, String amount, String description)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

    contentValues.put("title", title);
    contentValues.put("amount", amount);
    contentValues.put("description",description);


    db.insert("contacts", null, contentValues);
    return true;
}
public Cursor getData(int id){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor res =  db.rawQuery( "select * from contacts where id="+id+"", null );
    return res;
}
public int numberOfRows(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    int numRows = (int) DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(db, CONTACTS_TABLE_NAME);
    return numRows;
}
public boolean updateContact (Integer id, String title, String amount, String description)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put("title", title);
    contentValues.put("amount", amount);
    contentValues.put("description",description);

    db.update("contacts", contentValues, "id = ? ", new String[] { Integer.toString(id) } );
    return true;
}

public Integer deleteContact (Integer id)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    return db.delete("contacts",
            "id = ? ",
            new String[] { Integer.toString(id) });
}
public ArrayList<String> getAllContacts()
{
    ArrayList<String> array_list = new ArrayList<>();
    hp = new HashMap();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor res =  db.rawQuery( "select * from contacts", null );
    res.moveToFirst();
    while(res.isAfterLast() == false){
        array_list.add(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(CONTACTS_COLUMN_TITLE)));
        array_list.add(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(CONTACTS_COLUMN_AMOUNT)));
        array_list.add(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(CONTACTS_COLUMN_DESC)));
        System.out.print("database data:" +res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(CONTACTS_COLUMN_TITLE)));
        System.out.print("database data:" +res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(CONTACTS_COLUMN_AMOUNT)));
        System.out.print("database data:" +res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(CONTACTS_COLUMN_DESC)));
        System.out.print("List holds:" + array_list);
        res.moveToNext();
    }
    return array_list;
}
}
```

In **Details.java** where i insert the data on button click this way:

```js
public void run(View view) {
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            int Value = extras.getInt("id");
            if (Value > 0) {
                if (mydb.updateContact(id_To_Update, title.getText().toString(), amount.getText().toString(), description.getText().toString())) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyBasket.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Not Updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } else {
                if (mydb.insertContact(title.getText().toString(), amount.getText().toString(), description.getText().toString())) {
                    showAlertDialog();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "not done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

**MyBasket.java** is where i display the listview of the data added this way:
in my OnCreate()

```js
mydb = new DBHelper(this);

        ArrayList array_list = mydb.getAllContacts();

        ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter =
                new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array_list);

        //adding it to the list view.
        obj = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        obj.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

Still i am unable to display.I dont know where i am going wrong.Any help or suggestions will be much apprecated.

My Logcat:

```js
03-29 19:35:54.849    3834-3834/com.snappy.stevekamau.cosmeticsapp E/SQLiteLog﹕ (1) table contacts has no column named amount
03-29 19:35:54.949    3834-3834/com.snappy.stevekamau.cosmeticsapp E/SQLiteDatabase﹕ Error inserting amount=Ksh.8.0 title=District 9 description=Action, Sci-Fi, Thriller
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table contacts has no column named amount (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO contacts(amount,title,description) VALUES (?,?,?)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:882)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:493)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1467)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1339)
            at com.snappy.stevekamau.cosmeticsapp.DBHelper.insertContact(DBHelper.java:60)
            at com.snappy.stevekamau.cosmeticsapp.Details.run(Details.java:82)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3602)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4100)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17016)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4838)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:875)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:642)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Try using ArrayList<String> instead of just ArrayList

Comment: @Gulfaran i tried that and still there is no difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the value of array_list if you put a breakpoint at

```
 ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter =
                new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array_list);
```

Comment: ,i did as you suggested and apparently `obj` returns `null` and the `array_list size=0`.i dont understand what this means

Comment: Basically you are not returning any data to put in your listview, if you check you logcat you are trying to put information into a column called 'amount' but this doesn't exist in your table, check your table!

Comment: see my edit on DBHelper.java ,still getting the same logcat output

Comment: Clear data on your app, the database will already exist so it won't recreate it.

Comment: It has worked!!It is showing the data as a listview!Thanks dave i appreciate it!But then  have another issue.I would like to put the data from columns title,amount,description in one row instead of them separated in separate rows.How do i handle this?

Comment: You will need to create a custom adapter if you wish to display them completely in separate columns, if you just need them to display with no sorting etc then just combine your query results into one string, simple_list_item is not designed to handle multiple columns as far as I am aware

Answer (score 0):

```
array_list.add(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(CONTACTS_COLUMN_NAME)));       
System.out.Println("database data:" +res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(CONTACTS_COLUMN_NAME));
System.out.Println("List holds:" + array_list);
res.moveToNext();
```

put that in your code in the getallcontacts function and see whether the output shows the arraylist actually being populated correctly.

Comment: `.Println` cannot be resolved.I have placed your code right under  `while(res.isAfterLast() == false){`

Comment: Are you using Eclipse? Basically going on Daves answer and your comment the array _list isn't receiving any data from the getallcontacts. So I'm guessing the res.getString isn't pulling any data from the database.

Comment: The insert call hasn't been successful because one of the columns hasn't got the name amount

Comment: I changed PrintIn to print,i am using android studio

Comment: i have been working all night on this code.I applied the changes on DBHelper,see edit.Still same logcat output